# Get month and year with get_where and int type column mysql in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a column like this

[image]

I use date() to fill my mysql column. 
I want get all data where month and year like this (my model)

```
public function export_to_excel($perkara, $bulan, $tahun)
{
$query = $this->db->get_where('berkas_tuduhan', [
        'jenis_perkara' => $perkara,
        "DATE_FORMAT(tanggal_dibuat,'%Y-%m')" => $bulan,
        "DATE_FORMAT(tanggal_dibuat,'%Y-%m')" => $tahun
    ]);
    if ($query->num_rows() != 0) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

i use $bulan = 'MM' and $tahun = 'YYYY' . Please help me, thank you

Comment: In your DB it saves as unix time format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using unix time format, you could use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` to get the result :

```php
public function export_to_excel($perkara, $bulan, $tahun)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('berkas_tuduhan', [
        'jenis_perkara' => $perkara,
        "MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(tanggal_dibuat))" => $bulan,
        "YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(tanggal_dibuat))" => $tahun
    ]);
    if ($query->num_rows() != 0) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```